# Consider more cusps in modular form?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

A holomorphic function on $\mathbb{H}$ is called a modular form of weight $k$ for SL$_2(\mathbb{Z)}$ if it satisfies

1. $f(Mz)= (cz+d)^kf(z) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall M \in$ SL$_2(\mathbb{Z)}$
2. $f$ is holomorphic at the cusp $\infty$

I know that its possible to consider congruence subgroups like $$\Gamma_0(m) = \{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} : c \equiv 0 \mod m
\}$$ instead of SL$_2(\mathbb{Z)}$.
But why do we have to consider more than one cusp in this case? I dont really understand it and i hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: The brief answer is that modular forms for a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ naturally arise from differential forms on a quotient $\Gamma\setminus\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane. This quotient is not compact, but it can be made so by adding a few points (the cusps), which vary with $\Gamma$; and enforcing some sanity condition at this points is necessary to product a nice class of functions.

Comment: If you allow poles at the other cusps then the obtained space of meromorphic modular forms isn't finite dimensional anymore, it isn't an Hilbert space for the Petersson inner product and the Hecke operators aren't bounded normal operators so you won't have the decomposition in eigenforms. The meromorphic functions transforming like modular forms and having poles on $\mathbb{H}$ or at some of the cusps are quotients of modular forms. $\Gamma\setminus\mathbb{H}$ is a Riemann surface, together with its cusps  it is compact which changes a lot of its properties.